# Posting Selected UITableView rows to a MySQL database table via UIButton

Tags: php, mysql, swift, uitableview, storyboard

[This is how my storyboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2CA9.png)

Basically I have two UITableViews which are connected to tables on my MySQL database. I want it to send the selected rows(or if possible the rows with the accessory type .checkmark) as a POST to a table in my database by pressing a button. I have the PHP code ready and I am able to make POST requests and update a table in MySQL, that's not the problem here. I want the selected rows in my UITableView to be sent to that specific PHP code when the button is pressed.

```
 @IBAction func selected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
            
            let currentItem = currentCell.textLabel!.text
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "You Selected " + currentItem! , preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil)
            
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            let url = NSURL(string: "url")
            // locahost MAMP - change to point to your database server
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            var dataString = "secretWord=---" // starting POST string with a secretWord
            
            // the POST string has entries separated by &
            
            dataString = dataString + "&currentitem=\(currentItem!)"
            
            // add items as name and value
            // convert the post string to utf8 format
            
            let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) // convert to utf8 string
            
            do
            {
                
                // the upload task, uploadJob, is defined here
                
                let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
                {
                    data, response, error in
                    
                    if error != nil {
                        
                    }
                }
                uploadJob.resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to do this, which I guess is just a mess of a code since I'm still a beginner but yeah i hope this kind of sends a general message of my problem to you

I know you can use a IBAction to call a function that could send it to the php code but I'm just not sure on how to exactly code it.
I tried to use if statements with the tableView and the didSelectRowAt function inside of an IBAction but nothing seemed to work.
I have not found any sources online about it when I tried to search for it.

Comment: I am trying my best to explain my problem, I have now also included code I tried to hopefully have people understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: That is a huge improvement. Thanks. So, not to belabor the point, your question is not how to build a request and send it to PHP (which in turn, saves it to MySQL), but merely how to detect that multiple rows in the table were selected?

Comment: in a simplified manner yes, i want the button to detect the rows selected and send the content of said row to my php code

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to permit the selection of multiple rows in a table, we use [`allowsMultipleSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection), which you can set either programmatically or in Interface Builder.

Then in `didSelectRowAt` (and `didDeselectRowAt`), rather than just using the indexPath that was passed to the delegate method, instead use [`indexPathsForSelectedRows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows).

And if you don't want to send the updates to the server every time a row is selected and deselected, but instead in an `@IBAction` method associated with a button, then remove the network request from `didSelectRowAt` (and `didDeselectRowAt`), and instead put it in your button’s `@IBAction`, again using `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

---

Note, rather than `currentitem=...`, you will likely want to send it as an array, e.g. `currentitems[0]=13` and `currentitems[1]=42`, etc., separated with `&`.

Comment: Alright thank you, but how do i use indexPathsForSelectedRows, since if it’s declared in the function i cant use it in the IBAction, i tried looking at the linked apple developer website but it doesnt seem to give me enough information for me to understand

Comment: You should have an `@IBOutlet` hooked up for your table view. Then the `@IBAction` for your button can reference the table view.